# Git - Restore lost commits

Tags: git

As the team I'm on has grown, we have seen a number of situations where commits get lost due to merge mistakes.

We are working on the educational aspect already, but when this happens, what are some of the best ways in git to restore the lost commits - I've heard of using commands like `git bisect` and manually checking out each commit. What else is out there to help?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll try these out and give a summary the next time we run into a scenario like this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need [git fsck --lost-found](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what this does besides checking validity and connectivity of objects?

Comment: From the manpage for git-fsck: `Write dangling objects into .git/lost-found/commit/ or .git/lost-found/other/, depending on type. If the object is a blob, the contents are written into the file, rather than its object name.`

Answer (score 2):

`git reflog` can be used to find out the commit hashes of commits that are no longer on any branch but haven't yet been gc'ed.

Comment: Seems like reflog only stores local activity and is less usable on remotes.